# geom_bar(), Y-axis goes way above data value

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to visualize a data frame from a survey. I'm currently trying to plot a barplot with geom_bar(), that takes in "Life Satisfaction" as the y-axis, and "Family Values" as the x-axis. Note that the survey answer for Life Satisfaction is 1(very unsatisfied) to 10(very satisfied).

But for some reason when I try to plot this barplot, the y-axis goes way above 10, and I don't understand why.

This is my code:

```
df1 %>%
  filter(df1$B_COUNTRY_ALPHA == "PAK") %>%
  drop_na(Q49) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Q1, y = Q49, fill = B_COUNTRY_ALPHA)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Family Value",
       y = "Life Satisfaction")
```

This is the graph that I get when I run it:
[image]

This is the first 20 rows of data that I want to work with:

[image]

*On a side note: I was thinking of finding the mean of the Life Satisfaction data and maybe that will make the plot make sense but I am not sure how to do that*

@GregorThomas I followed your instructions and I got this.

```
structure(list(B_COUNTRY_ALPHA = c("PAK", "PAK", "PAK", "PAK", 
"PAK", "PAK", "PAK", "PAK", "PAK", "PAK", "PAK", "PAK", "PAK", 
"PAK", "PAK", "PAK", "PAK", "PAK", "PAK", "PAK"), Q49 = c(7, 
10, 10, 5, 1, 6, 6, 10, 10, 10, 4, 4, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 10, 
8), Q1 = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), Q2 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
4, 1, 2, 2, 2), Q3 = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, NA, 2, 4, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2), Q4 = c(3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2), Q5 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4), Q6 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4), Q57 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1), Q106 = c(7, 5, 
10, 4, 10, 7, 1, 10, 10, 10, 1, 10, 1, 10, 10, 10, 9, 4, 10, 
6), Q107 = c(7, 6, 5, 5, 10, 3, 1, 10, 10, NA, 1, 1, 1, 10, 3, 
10, 10, 8, 10, 4), Q108 = c(7, 9, 1, 4, 1, 1, 10, 10, 5, 10, 
10, 10, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 3), Q109 = c(6, 4, 1, 4, 1, 
1, 1, 10, 10, 1, 6, 2, 10, 5, 10, 1, 10, 9, 1, 4), Q110 = c(6, 
3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 10, 1, 10, 3, 1, 3), Q112 = 
c(8, 
8, 10, 6, 10, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, NA, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 7), Q163 = c(6, 2, 10, 7, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, NA, 10, 
10, 6, 10, 3, NA, 8, 7, NA, 9), Q164 = c(4, 9, 10, 8, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, NA, 8, 10, 10, 10), Q222 = c(2, 
1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, NA, 1, NA, 2, 3, NA, 3), 
Q260 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1), Q262 = c(33, 21, 60, 18, 60, 50, 45, 29, 62, 
46, 35, 40, 30, NA, 45, NA, 30, 50, 36, 34), Q273 = c(1, 
6, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
Q275 = c(0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, 3, NA, 
1, 1, 0, 1), Q281 = c(8, 0, 3, 0, 10, 3, 4, 6, 3, 8, 4, 4, 
4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: `geom_bar` performs an implicit counting step, since it has a default `stat = "count"` parameter. It is reporting how many observations had `Q1` == 1. You might want `stat = "mean"`, perhaps. What output are you seeking?

Comment: I want a plot that can help me visualize how this "Family Value" impacts "Life Satisfaction".

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted a few rows of data, perhaps `df1 %>%  filter(df1$B_COUNTRY_ALPHA == "PAK") %>% drop_na(Q49) %>% slice(1:20) %>% dput()` for the first 20 rows.

Comment: @GregorThomas I've posted the first 20 rows of data that I want to work with.

Comment: Okay, I can't work with a picture of a table, (please use `dput` so it's copy/pasteable!!!), but how many rows of data do you have? When you look at the entire subset of data you're trying to plot, what does `table(this_data$Q49)` show?

Comment: Try a heatmap of 2d bin counts `df1%>%ggplot(aes(x=Q1,y=Q49))+geom_bin2d()`

Comment: @GregorThomas okayy, I edited that part in. Is that correct?

Comment: Yup, that's a copy/pasteable R object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple ideas using your sample data:

- Use a dodged bar plot:

```
sample_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Q1), fill = factor(Q49))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single')) +
  labs(x = "Family Value",
       y = "Count of Responses",
       fill = "Life Satisfaction")
```

[image]

- Use facets:

```
sample_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Q49), fill = factor(Q49))) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(x = "Life Satisfaction",
       y = "Count of Responses",
       fill = "Life Satisfaction") +
  facet_wrap(vars(paste("Family Value", Q1)))
```

[image]

- Use a heat map:

```
sample_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Q1),y = factor(Q49))) +
  geom_bin2d() +
  coord_fixed() + 
  labs(y = "Life Satisfaction", x = "Family Value")
```

[image]